# How to create a function of n variables (python)

Tags: python, julia

I would like to create a function of n variables in python, such as

```
n=3
def func(n1,n2,n3):
    return sum(n1+n2+n3)

func(1,2,3) = 6
func(3,3,3)=9
```

or if n=4,

```
n=4
def func(n1,n2,n3,n4):
    return sum(n1+n2+n3+n4)

func(1,2,3,4) = 10
```

There is a perfect example of someone doing this in julia:
[How to create a function of n variables (Julia)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324260/how-to-create-a-function-of-n-variables-julia)

using this solution

```
function f(x...)
     sum(x)
end

julia> f(1,2,3)
6
```

However I do not know how to translate the ellipses type input to python

Comment: the `args` keyword is used in Python, see [can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function).

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia, `args` is not a keyword - it's a regular name of the argument

Comment: yes, right, thanks for correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python supports variable arguments too

```
def f(*x):
    return sum(x)
```

The `x` inside the function will *also* be a tuple, like in Julia.

Julia:

```
julia> function f(x...)
        x
       end

f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(2,4,5)
(2, 4, 5)
```

Python:

```py
>>> def f(*x):
...  return x
... 
>>> f(2,4,5)
(2, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unpacking operator (`*`):

```
def func(*x):
    return sum(x)
```

Note that when using this notation `x` is `tuple` inside `func`, which `sum` happilly accepts.

Comment: You actually aren't using the unpacking operator.